# How to see the iTunes shared library from Linux Banshee?

Tags: ubuntu, music

I'm trying to see my friend's Mac iTunes library through Banshee and can't get it to work.
The daap is already installed and i still can't list their musics.

Is there a way to make this work on Ubuntu?

Comment: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1347 ?

Answer (score 1):

I got my information from [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13552/access-itunes-shares-from-rhythmbox) and from my own experience.

iTunes feeds are encrypted to lock you out from doing exactly what you are trying to do. Banshee will actually show "You are running iTunes greater than version 7" (which you probably are) as one of the possible reasons it is failing, and explains this.

There is no workaround that I know of if you wish to stream Apple protected files.